# Manually insert a WordPress plugin inside custom theme's header.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

All right, so I have an issue I'm trying to work through involving WordPress plugins. I have found a gallery plugin that I like--has pretty much everything I need--but the problem is that placing the shortcode in the content editor causes it to be placed below a banner image that I have (this banner image is stored in my custom theme's `header.php` file and it has to go there because of the layout of the site I'm working on).

What I want to do is call the plugin inside my header.php before this banner image...but I am having trouble figuring out what I need to do in order to accomplish this. I read about the need to potentially remove the register_activation_hook or activate_pluginname actions when I manually call the plugin in my header.php file...do I need to somehow incorporate these or create functionality similar in my `header.php` file?

This is what I'm aiming for in my header.php file (I am only looking to load this gallery plugin for the home page, hence the check to see if the page id is the home page id):

```
  <div id="Container_Body" class="clearfix">
    <div id="topbox">
      <?php 
          $id = get_the_ID();
          $hpid = get_option('page_on_front');
          if($id == $hpid)
          {
            code to display plugin
          }
      ?>
      <div class="GalleryPlugin">
         <?php code to display gallery plugin ?>
      </div>
      <div class="giantBanner" style="background: rgb(0, 141, 175);">
        <img title="Main-Header-Banner" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/Market-Crowd.jpg" alt="Market Crowd">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
  <?php 

   if(is_home() || is_front_page()) // this will check for homepage its a wp check
   {
        // echo the plugin shortcode here like
       echo do_shortcode('[gallery]');  // this will be any shortcode
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: This is perfect! But the only thing is....every time the a gallery is created with the plugin, there will be new shortcode for it. That shortcode would need to be manually replaced in the code above in the do_shortcode() function...is there away around this at all?

Comment: The idea for this is, the short code may have an id attribute, you can make a custom function in your functions.php file, pass that ID to that functions as argument and then in that function call this short code and then call the new function in header

Comment: Is this what you mean?

 `<?php
  function get_plugin_id( $pluginid )
  {
    if(is_home() || is_front_page()) // this will check for homepage its a wp check
     {
          // echo the plugin shortcode here like
         echo do_shortcode('[foogallery id="'.$pluginid.'"]');  // this will be any shortcode
     }
   }
?>`

Comment: yup call `get_plugin_id($id); ` in header

Comment: I'm still a little confused...how exactly am I going to get the specific id of the plugin that I need? I know I need to pass it into my get_plugin_id function...but how exactly do I get that $id value?

Comment: here is an idea, edit the plugin , create a checkbox/status field for the galleries listing page, then save that status with id in the options table, then here you can get that option from the db